# Is it fine to choose 0 lag for adf test in my data?

Tags: time-series, stationarity

The level values weren't stationary so I took percent changes $(P_t-P_{t-1})/P_{t-1}$. Here's the data:
[image]
[image]

These are the PACFs to determine lags. I think the lag can be 0, or 7 or 11 in case of GDP and it must be 0 for MVA.

[image]

From the p-values (2nd value in bracket) I can conclude that both are stationary. But when I take higher lags for GDP (like 7) I got non-stationary. MVA seems to be stationary for all lags. What should I do? Should I take that high lag or not?

[image]

[image]

I plan on building a VAR/VEC model from hereon to check for granger causality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.)
Please look into these vids:

VAR with Python
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Ye0CsfRDJg

AR orders in general
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-2C4eO4cPQ

2.)
There you can see that we normally ignore lag 0 in a PACF. A lag of 0 for a series with itself would mean you would explain the time series by itself with no shift. That doesnt make sense, as you would explain the series by an exact copy of it. So you have to go to higher lags in generall when interpreting PACF. Now to the ADF.

3.)
It is possible that the ADF test tells you, that at later parts a series is no longer stationary. See here: (but for R, but it deals with the theory) https://www.r-econometrics.com/timeseries/stationarity/. And that means yeah it is no longer stationary. Going with higher lags also doesnt mean, that these will be significant in the end for a VAR as you see in the vids.

4.)
If one variable is stationary and the other is not at lag 7. You **should** transform both variables with log and differences for VAR in differences. As you
not mix up transformations and non transformations in a VAR

5.)
In general you could do:

- a VAR in levels (if all features are stationary)
- a VECM, transforming no variable and checking for unit root (that would be still one chance for you to circumvent transformation and use lag 7 without transformation
- VAR in differences, a VAR with transformed variables

*Update*
not really the same as percentage change
[image: perc]

Comment: Thank you so much! Been struggling with this for 3 days. Could you confirm if differencing is same as taking percentage change?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: How do I choose the right lag? I watched both the videos. Should I choose the highest possible one?

Comment: If your PACF suggest 12, choose 12 in your model. The ADF is only there to check if you have unit root and tells you if you have to transform your variable or if a VECM with an error correction term might be able.

Comment: It's not becoming stationary even after log and then differencing, what should I do?

Comment: you may difference it a second time, but normally that should be enough. You may also want to post sime output. We can create a chat, although I'm busy the whole day. we can talk about it surely tomorrow

Comment: In the end we used log diff for MVA and log diff gdp "per capita" I helped the OP in getting a VAR lag order in dependence of academic literature and by a lag test. Was happy to help